# Connecting to guests localhost from host in VirtualBox

Tags: localhost, ubuntu-14.04, virtualbox, nat, hosts

I'm trying to connect to my virtual server which is running on `Ubuntu 14.04` in VirtualBox. I've tried portforwarding on my own in the VirtualBox settings but that didn't work, also when I tried setting my network adapter to host-only for some reason I lose internetconnection on my Ubuntu. My host is running `Windows 10 64bit Education`.

Which settings should I use to make this work? [current settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Apqrb.png)

Answer (score 0):

To make connection from host to virtual machine (VM), you don't have to use port forwarding feature. You only need to set the VM's network mode to bridged mode, then assign the IP manually within the same network as the host computer. That way, host and VM can connect each other and the VM doesn't lose the internet connection

Answer (score 0):

On Centos/RedHat is had to run the following commands to stop the iptables. Unfortunately I don't know the equivalent for uBuntu.

service iptables save

service iptables stop

chkconfig iptables off